# Percona corrupt table

Tags: mysql, database, percona

I have one database where one of its tables gets corrupt after some days. Once it gets corrupt it doesn't appear in table list and if I try to create it again I get `Table 'svb.rate_list' doesn't exist`

Why that table could corrupt? Any idea how to avoid that?

I am using `5.6.16-64.2-56 Percona Server`

Comment: Are you sure the table is not dropped somewhere? Can you search for strings like drop table in your project?

Comment: Sure. There is no drops over any table in database

Answer (score 0):

Corrupt tables, 99% of the time, only appear in MyISAM-engine'd tables. Ensure this table is InnoDB. Check the output of `dmesg` to ensure no disk errors/disk corruption.